# Нужно вернуть три значения из функции JavaScript(json)

Tags: javascript, json, xhr

Достаную данные про курс трёх валют из сайта банка Украины.
Выводит вот сюда[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но Я хочу сделать еще конвертацию,и чтобы опять не отправлять еще раз запрос мне нужны вернуть данные с функции.
Ссылка на сайт-[Сайт](https://yurakhomitsky.github.io/exchange%20rates/)
Вот сама функция:

```js
window.addEventListener("load",checkrate(),false);
function checkrate(e){
 const XHR=new XMLHttpRequest();
 var URItwo=`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json`;
 var cursUSD;
 var cursEUR;
 var cursPLN;
 XHR.addEventListener("readystatechange",function(){
 if((XHR.readyState===4) && (XHR.status===200)){
   let resultwo=JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
            console.log(resultwo);
            for(var key in resultwo){
             if (resultwo[key].cc=="USD") {
               rateone.innerHTML=resultwo[key].txt +` `+resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2)+`грн`;
              cursUSD=resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2);
              console.log(cursUSD);
             }
             if (resultwo[key].cc=="EUR") {
               ratetwo.innerHTML=resultwo[key].txt +` `+resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2)+`грн`;
              cursEUR=resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2);
               console.log(cursEUR);
             }
             if (resultwo[key].cc=="PLN") {
               ratetree.innerHTML=resultwo[key].txt +` `+resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2)+`грн`;
              cursPLN=resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2);
              console.log(cursPLN);
             }
            }
            
        }

    }, false);
  
XHR.open("GET",URItwo);
XHR.send();

}
```

Comment: дак и верните объект вида `var result = { usd: ... , eur: ... , pln: ...}` в чем проблема?

Comment: А после чего это написать,просто внутри функции есть функция,а мне нужны эти данные на другое событие кнопки